# Chrome Extension: Icon from URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to make a Chrome extension, and for some reasons beyond me, I have to load images from a url hosted elsewhere...

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 1,
  "description": "A something something something",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "logo_white.gif"
    }

}
```

How can I load favicon.ico and logo_white.gif from http://www.example.com/favicon.ico and http://www.example.com/logo_white.gif instead? I'm baffled since I'm reasonably new to chrome extensions and their use of JSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the data at runtime as an image tag, then stick it in a canvas object, extract an ImageData and pass that to the [setIcon](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon) API.

Something like the following in a background.js would do the trick:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({imageData: imageData});
}
img.src = "http://www.example.com/logo_white.gif";
```

Comment: added this after second line -- `canvas.style.display = 'none';`
⠀
& this after last line -- `canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);`
⠀
so the canvas didn't munge up / to clean up our popup panel

Comment: Hello, is this approach still applicable for MV3? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use icons located outside of your extension. Your extension will be installed on a local computer and Google Chrome should be able to get your extension's icon when there's no internet connection available.