# How do I dynamically set Chrome Extension Icon based on an image from a different URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Currently I am migrating my MV2 chrome extension into MV3.

With my MV2 extension, I can dynamically set my extension's icon using an image from a remote url using a code similar to the answer of this stackoverflow topic  : [Chrome Extension: Icon from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828515/chrome-extension-icon-from-url)

With the introduction of manifest-v3 and service workers, the service worker lost access to the DOM, making calls to creating instances of Image and canvas impossible.

My MV3-extension is now using nodeJS. I was looking into a combination of JSDOM, node-canvas, and OffScreenCanvas to implement the original code but no success as of yet.

What would be the best approach to set the icon dynamically (chrome.actions.setIcon), based on an image remotely hosted?

Thank you very much.

Comment: createImageBitmap + OffScreenCanvas can be successfully used in a service worker, no need for JSDOM or any external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) in the comments for anybody looking into this same issue.

> createImageBitmap + OffScreenCanvas can be successfully used in a service worker, no need for JSDOM or any external libraries.